Getting AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext exception after upgrading jdk 17 from 8 and in Springboot 3.2.2
I have upgraded the Java and Springboot version to 17 and 3.2.2.
But I am getting  Application start failed with below errors logs:
[ "message": {"Message": "The following 1 profile is active: \"local\""}}



["level": "WARN", "Timestamp":"2024-09-25T18:16:18.634+05:30","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context



AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext", "message":{"Message": "Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure while processing configuration class "}}



{"level":"ERROR", "Timestamp":"2824-09-25T18:16:18.674+05:30","logger":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication" "message": {"Message": "Application run failed"}}

I tried to change many dependency versions but nothing works.
